# Turn on multiple Samsung TVs by connecting them with HDMI cable?

Tags: hdmi

When my computer boots up, I would like to start 3 connected Samsung TVs. The computer is connected to the first Samsung TV via the PulseEight USB-CEC adapter and sends the [CEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_Electronics_Control) (Consumer Electronics Control) event. Would the other 2 TVs turn on, too, if I connect TV1 => TV2 => TV3 with HDMI? Shouldn't the first TV kick off a CEC event to the second one and so forth? Thanks! :)

Comment: Have you tried setting this up?

Comment: @Anaksunaman Not yet, trying to waste as less time as possible so I'm first looking for experts who might be able to rule this out quickly in case it is nonsense.

Comment: No most likely it would not work. All TVs want CEC logical address 0 and they all want to try allocating it for themselves. As soon as they notice someone else already has it they might try secondary address or give up. So only one TV could wake up, but in no case you should connect HDMI input connectors together.